# How do I integrate $x^5(4+x^2)^{-1/2}$?

Tags: integration, substitution

I just started learning substitution and I can't seem to solve this exercise.
I'm using $x = 2sinh(t)$

Full Solution:

$32\int(sinh(t)*(cosh^2(t)-1)^2=$

$32\int(sinh(t)*(cosh^4(t)-2cosh^2(t)+1)=$

$32\int(cosh^4(t)sinh(t)-2cosh^2(t)sinh(t)+sinh(t))=$

$32(\int(cosh^4(arcsinx)sinh(arcsinx)-2\int(cosh^2(arcsinx)sinh(arcsinhx)+\int(sinh(arcsinx)))=$

$32(\int((1-x^2)^2*x) - 2\int((1-x^2)*x) + \int(x))=$

Comment: More generally: $\int x^m\left(a+bx^n\right)^p\, dx$ (where $m,n,p$ are rational) is integrable (in elementary functions) if and only if at least one of the conditions holds: $p\in\Bbb Z, \frac{m+1}{n}\in\Bbb Z, p+\frac{m+1}{n}\in\Bbb Z$. If $p\in\Bbb Z$, it's simple (use substitution $u=x^{1/\text{lcm}(a,b)}$, where $m=\frac{c_1}{a}, n=\frac{c_2}{b},\gcd(c_1,a)=\gcd(c_2,b)=1$). If $\frac{m+1}{n}\in\Bbb Z$, use substitution $u^s=a+bx^n$, where $p=\frac{r}{s}, \gcd(r,s)=1$.  If $p+\frac{m+1}{n}\in\Bbb Z$, use substitution $u^sx^n=a+bx^n$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $4+x^2=u^2$ and note that $x^5=(x)(x^4)=(x)(u^2-4)^2$.

But if you want to use a $\sinh$ substitution, let $x=2\sinh t$. You will end up integrating a constant times $\sinh^5 t$, which you can rewrite as $(\sinh t)(\cosh^2 t-1)^2$. And now another substitution.

**Added detail** Let $4+x^2=u^2$, with $u$ positive. Then $2x\,dx=2u\,du$  and therefore $x\,dx=u\,du$. Note that $(4+x^2)^{-1/2}=\frac{1}{u}$. We have $x^5=(x)(x^4)=x(u^2-4)^2$. Substituting we find that our integral is 
$$\int \frac{(u^2-4)^2 u}{u}\,du.$$
Thus we want
$$\int (u^4-8u^2+16)\,du.$$
This is equal to $\frac{u^5}{5}-\frac{8u^3}{3}+16u+C$.

Finally, replace $u$ by $(4+x^2)^{1/2}$.

Comment: That's what I did to solve the exercise but the result I got to was way different from the result my professor gave us in class.

Comment: Hard to know what happened without detail about what you did. There may have been a little mistake along the way. And sometimes two different-looking antiderivatives are essentially the same, only differing by a constant, which gets taken care of by the arbitrary constant of integration.

Comment: Now that you have added detail, it looks as if you used $x=2\sinh t$, despite what the earlier post says. I cannot be sure of what you have written, but you should end up integrating $32(\cosh^2 t-1)^2\sinh t$.  You seem to have reached that, since the $\cosh t$ in your expression partly cancel.

Comment: I made a mistake in my post. I hadn't noticed sorry. I do end up integrating that and my solution is still wrong. Should I post my whole solution?

Comment: As to mistake, as I wrote earlier, it looks as if so far things are fine. Maybe you did not cancel the $\cosh t$. Or maybe everything went well, and there was trouble with the rewriting in terms of $x$. The first way I suggested is quite a bit quicker.

Comment: Posting the whole solution is necessary if one is to spot a mistake, if mistake was made.  If you modify and then post, please leave a message if ou want me to look at it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and patience so far, I've edited most of the solution into the original post.

Comment: After you multiplied through by $\sinh t$, which was unnecessary, things are not good.  You should get (sub. $u=\cosh t$, or just write it down), $32\left(\frac{\cosh^5 t}{5}-\frac{2\cosh^3 t}{3}+\cosh t\right)+C$. And then $\cosh t=\sqrt{\sinh^2 t+1}$. Finally, replace $\sinh t$ by $x/2$. Do try my simple way!

Comment: I'll try to solve it using your method, it does seem a lot more simple. I have to go away from the computer for a while. Do you think you could give me a step by step of how you integrate after the substitution? Thanks for all the help

Comment: You mean after my suggested substiution?  Or do you have trouble with the integration in my comment? That's just ler $u=\cosh t$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, 
let, $x=2\tan \theta\ \implies dx=2\sec^2\theta \ d\theta $
$$\int \frac{x^5}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}\ dx$$$$=\int \frac{(2\tan\theta)^5}{\sqrt{4+4\tan^2\theta}}(2\sec^2\theta \ d\theta)$$
$$=32\int \frac{\tan^5\theta \sec^2\theta}{|\sec\theta|}\ d\theta$$
Assuming $0<\theta<\pi/2$
$$=32\int \frac{\tan^5\theta \sec^2\theta}{\sec\theta}\ d\theta$$
$$=32\int (\tan^2\theta)^2 \sec\theta\tan\theta\ d\theta$$

$$=32\int (\sec^2\theta-1)^2 \sec\theta\tan\theta\ d\theta$$
$$=32\int (\sec^4\theta-2\sec^2\theta+1) \ d(\sec\theta)$$
$$=32\left(\frac{\sec^5\theta}{5}-\frac{2\sec^3\theta}{3}+\sec\theta\right)+C$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I'm still new to substitution could you explain how
$secθtanθ dθ$ turns into $d(secθ)$?

Comment: $\sqrt{\sec^2\theta}=|\sec\theta|$

Comment: OK, notice, $$\frac{d(\sec\theta)}{d\theta}=\sec\theta\tan\theta\implies d(\sec\theta)=\sec\theta\tan\theta\ d\theta $$

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Could you explain your next step as well?

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot I want to know how to cancel the absolute ?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{x^5}{(4+x^2)^{1/2}} dx$$

It seems like you're trying to take advantage of the identity $1+\sinh^2 x = \cosh^2 x$. But note that the term in parenthesis is not quite of this form. We need to accommodate for the $4$; thus we want to get $4+4\sinh^2 u$. So let $x = 2\sinh u$ and $dx = 2\cosh u du$. Then,

$$\int \frac{2^5\sinh^5 u}{(4+4\sinh^2 u)^{1/2}} 2\cosh u\ du$$

$$= 32\int \frac{\sinh^5 u}{2(1+\sinh^2 u)^{1/2}} 2\cosh u\ du$$

$$= 32 \int \frac{\sinh^5 u}{2\cosh u} 2\cosh u\ du$$

$$= 32 \int \sinh^5 u\ du$$

From here you can use a reduction formula or apply integration by parts.